# Using regex to only match those Strings which use escape character correctly (according to Java syntax)?

Tags: java, regex

take these strings for example:

> "hello world\n" (correct - regex should match this)
>
> "I'm happy \ here" (this is incorrect as the escape character is not
>   used correctly - regex should not match this one)

I've tried searching on google but didn't find anything helpful.

I want this one to be used in a parser which only parses string literals from a java code file.

Here is the the regex I used:

```
"\\\"(\\[tbnrf\'\"\\])*[a-zA-Z0-9\\`\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\_\\-\\+\\=\\|\\{\\[\\}\\]\\;\\:\\'\\/\\?\\>\\.\\<\\,]\\\""
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" I'd say, using regex. The regex is so complicated that even you as its author don't understand what it's doing. So code readability and maintainability suffer seriously. I'd throw the regex approach away (if your code architecture allows that) and replace it with a hand-written loop-based string method. But I'll look at the regex and try to understand it...

Comment: So you're looking for any sequence of an odd number of backslashes, that _isn't_ followed by t, b, n, r, f, double quote or single quote.  Right?  Seems fairly simple, compared to the regexp you've given!

Comment: You don't have to write anything to match illegal escapes, only legal escapes, and you've done that wih `\\[tnrbf\'\"\\]`.

Comment: I would use antlr (http://www.antlr.org) for complex regex.

Comment: @EJP Actually that's too simple.  Backslash followed by characters _other_ than those is legal if it's the second backslash of a pair.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I'm actually doing one my school project in which we are restricted to use the regex.

Comment: @Hooman I can't use _antlr_. I'm restricted to use regex as it is my school project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you gave us the regex in Java String literal form, like

```
String regex = \"(\[tbnrf'"\])*[a-zA-Z0-9\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\|\{\[\}\]\;\:\'\/\?\>\.\<\,]\";
```

Unpacking that from Java's String escaping syntax gives the raw regex:

```
\"(\[tbnrf'"\])*[a-zA-Z0-9\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\|\{\[\}\]\;\:\'\/\?\>\.\<\,]\"
```

That consists of:

- `\"` matching a double-quote character (Java String literal begins here). Escaping the double quotes with backslash isn't necessary: `"` on its own is ok as well.
- `(\[tbnrf'"\])*`: a group, repeated 0...n times. I guess you want that to match against the various Java backslash escapes, but that should read `(\\[tbnrf'"\\])*` with a double backslash in front and inside the character class. And maybe you want to cover the Java octal escapes as well (see [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)), giving `(\\[tbnrf01234567'"\\])*`
- ``` [a-zA-Z0-9\``\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\|\{\[\}\]\;\:\'\/\?\>\.\<\,] ```: a character class matching one character from a selected list of alphabetic and punctuation characters. I'd replace that with `[^"\\]`, meaning anything but double quote or backslash.
- `\"` matching a double-quote character (string literal ends here). Once again, no need to escape the double quote.

Besides the individual elements, the overall structure of the regex probably isn't what you want: You allow only strings beginning with any number of backslash escapes, followed by exactly one non-escape character, and this enclosed in a pair of double quotes.

The overall structure should instead be "(*backslash_escape*|*simple_character*)*"

So, the complete regex would be:

```
"(\\[tbnrf01234567'"\\]|[^"\\])*"
```

or, expressed in a Java literal:

```
String regex = "\"(\\\\[tbnrf01234567'\"\\\\]|[^\"\\\\])*\"";
```

And, although this is shorter than your original attempt, I'd still not call it readable and opt for a different implementation, not using regular expressions.

P.S. Although I did some testing with my regex, I'm not at all sure that it covers all relevant cases correctly.

P.P.S. There are the `\uxxxx` escapes, not yet covered by the regex.

Comment: Woo. It matched like a charm. Thank You.